# Delete an element from an array - React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, splice

Im making a table of materials that, when i press the delete button a material have to disappear and im using the **splice()** method but when i push the delete button of the first element, this action deletes all the elements of the array.

Here is the function that apparently make this happen but isn't working :(

```
RemoveMaterial = (material_id) => {

    let element = [...this.state.material_list];
    const material = element.findIndex((item) => item === material_id);
    const list = [...this.state.material_list];
    const consumption_list = [...this.state.material_consumption];
    const material_list = [...this.state.materials];
    list.splice(material)
    consumption_list.splice(material)
    material_list.splice(material)
    this.setState({
      material_list: list,
      material_consumption: consumption_list,
      materials: material_list,
    });
  };
```

Comment: `.splice(material, 1)` otherwise you are deleting till the end of the array. See [`splice` docs regarding the `deleteCount` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#deletecount)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
RemoveMaterial = (material_id) => {

  //...
  
  const list = [...this.state.material_list];
  list.splice(material,1);
  this.setState({
      material_list: list
   });
   
   //...
  
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).